# PYTHON Obtaining the value of a 2d point by interpolating a list of surrounding points based on distance

Tags: python

I'm looking for a way to get the value of a 2d point (x,y) given a list of points with known value (x,y,value) by interpolating the values of nearby points based on distance.
The points coordinates and values are floats and they are not in a grid or any other kind of pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you 're looking for scipy's interpolate:

```
from scipy import interpolate

'''
Interpolate over a 2-D grid.

x, y and z are arrays of values used to approximate some function f: z = f(x, y). 
This class returns a function whose call method uses spline interpolation 
to find the value of new points.

'''

x = np.arange(-5.01, 5.01, 0.25)
y = np.arange(-5.01, 5.01, 0.25)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = np.sin(xx**2+yy**2)
f = interpolate.interp2d(x, y, z, kind='cubic')

# for new points
xnew = np.arange(-5.01, 5.01, 1e-2)
ynew = np.arange(-5.01, 5.01, 1e-2)
znew = f(xnew, ynew)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Is z = np.sin(xx**2+yy**2) just to create "random" z values or is there a reason for it?

Comment: Cheers! ^^
Yes, it's just for the sake of creating values for z. P.S. If you consider your question answered, mark it as such. ;)

Comment: I'm trying to make it work, i replaced the arange and sin with actual numpy arrays containing the x values, y values and z values and xnew, ynew with the coords of the point im looking for, im getting TypeError: m >= (kx+1)(ky+1) must hold

Comment: Can you try using scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator?

Comment: I'm getting ValueError: input data must be at least 2-D, i suspect it requires tuples or something for the points :/ No idea

Comment: Can you try skipping the np.meshgrid ? (sorry for all these suggestions, it's because I don't know exactly what you're trying to do)

Comment: I did skip the meshgrid in fact, maybe that's the problem, i have no clue what I'm doing :/ Can you please make your example code based on a list of tuples (x,y,z) with the new point (x,y) instead of "random" values, so i can understand what is it doing?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the time to help you further, for the time being. :( I hope I at least gave you some insight regarding what you can use. You may have to find yourself the way to utilize this for your own data. PS nice avatar and nickname ^^

Comment: Allright, i'll keep experimenting! And thanks :D MediEvil fan too uh? :D btw thanks again, i'll keep experimenting and seeing if i can somehow make it work!

Comment: Good luck! (Yeah, medievil was one of the first games I had on ps1, though I finished it for the first time when I was quite older, using an emulator) (offtopic mode off)